# Error when trying to migrate to Dagger Hilt

Tags: dependency-injection, dagger, dagger-hilt

I'm trying to migrate from Dagger (for Android) to Dagger Hilt.
I get the following error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:getDependencies'.
> Cannot change dependencies of dependency configuration ':app:prodDebugAndroidTestRuntimeClasspath' after it has been included in dependency resolution. Use 'defaultDependencies' instead of 'beforeResolve' to specify default dependencies for a configuration.
```

My dependencies

```
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$daggerVersion"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$daggerVersion"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVersion"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$daggerVersion"
    kaptAndroidTest "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$daggerVersion"

    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt_version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hilt_version"
```

Where both daggerVersion and hilt_version is 2.40.5

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by some Google License plugin (which I don't even know what is used for in the codebase, but doesn't matter, removing it solved the error).

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
    id 'com.google.firebase.appdistribution'
    //id 'com.google.android.gms.oss-licenses-plugin'
    ...
}
```